# Lazy loading with progress bar in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, instagram, lazy-loading, vue-router

Is there any way to use a progress bar with vue-router only when component is lazy loading (like Instagram does)?

Comment: I don't see how you actually measure the progress of an XHR request reliably because you need a total and a current count for your progress. This could have been used were it not deprecated today: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent I am interested in what other people have to say about attempting something like this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do. First, have your own global `progress-bar` component somewhere on the page, preferably, near the top like `Medium.com` or `Youtube.com`. During route transitions, you can manually trigger its lifecycle - visibility, and animation. But I don't recommend this approach unless you really need it.

The second approach is recommended. Create an Async component and use the official loading component flag to show the progress bar during the transition like this:

```
const AsyncComponent = () => ({
    // The component to load (should be a Promise)
    component: import('./MyComponent.vue'),
    // A component to use while the async component is loading
    loading: LoadingComponent,
    // A component to use if the load fails
    error: ErrorComponent,
    // Delay before showing the loading component. Default: 200ms.
    delay: 200,
    // The error component will be displayed if a timeout is
    // provided and exceeded. Default: Infinity.
    timeout: 3000
})
```

Read more about async component at [Vue.js docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html).

Comment: There are a few problems with this approach. First, in order to see the progress bar I have to invoke method start(), and in order for it to go away method finish() has to be invoked. I tried this with just a simple component (<h1>Loading</h1>), and even though I set the delay to 0, the loading component never shows, it goes straight to the 'MyComponent'...

Comment: Yes @FilipEgeric, there is a problem. With the first approach, you will have to do `start()` and `finish()`. With the second approach, you don't need to do that as you Vue controls the lifecycle of loading component. With your local development, you won't notice the difference. It will be shown when app is deployed to a real environment.